# Javascript common function for multiple input type=text & input type=color

Tags: javascript, css, html

In my body tag i have two input types(text & color). It works like this,

1. If you give the  hex value of color in the inputText, inputColor
   will automatically change to that color.
2. If you select the color via colorPicker, inputText will
   automatically change to the colorHex value you have chosen.

Below code works

```html
<body>

<input type="text" id="txtColor">
<input type="color" id="colColor" >
<script>

document.getElementById("txtColor").onblur = function() {myFunction1()};
document.getElementById("colColor").onchange = function() {myFunction2()};

function myFunction1() {
    //alert("Input field lost focus.");
    var txtColor = document.getElementById("txtColor").value;
 
    document.getElementById("txtColor").nextElementSibling.value = txtColor;
   
//    document.getElementById("colColor").value = txtColor;
}

function myFunction2() {
    //alert("Input field lost focus.");
    var colColor = document.getElementById("colColor").value;
    document.getElementById("colColor").previousElementSibling.value = colColor;
    
    //document.getElementById("txtColor").value = colColor;
}


</script>

</body>
```

What i am trying to do is, i have a table with multiple rows of above pair(inputText & inputColor). It should function similarly to above. I am trying with getElementsByClassName having a common classname for inputText and inputColor, so that it would update the sibling with hexColor value or color.

This is my current code, its not working. Currently getting error "Uncaught TypeError: txtColorClass.addEventListener is not a function"

```html
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtColor0" class="txtColorClass">
            <input type="color" id="colColor0" >            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtColor1" class="txtColorClass">
            <input type="color" id="colColor1" >            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtColor2" class="txtColorClass">
            <input type="color" id="colColor2" >            
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

<script>

var txtColorClass = document.getElementsByClassName("txtColorClass");
txtColorClass.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
  //event.target.style.background = "pink";    
  var txtColor = event.target.value; 
  event.target.nextElementSibling.value = txtColor;
  
}, true);


//document.getElementById("txtColor").onblur = function() {myFunction1()};
document.getElementById("colColor").onchange = function() {myFunction2()};

function myFunction1() {
    //alert("Input field lost focus.");
    var txtColor = document.getElementById("txtColor").value;
 
    document.getElementById("txtColor").nextElementSibling.value = txtColor;
   
//    document.getElementById("colColor").value = txtColor;
}

function myFunction2() {
    //alert("Input field lost focus.");
    var colColor = document.getElementById("colColor").value;
    document.getElementById("colColor").previousElementSibling.value = colColor;
    
    //document.getElementById("txtColor").value = colColor;
}


</script>

</body>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a node list - collection of elements. You need to loop through the collection to apply `addEventListener()`

Comment: Thank You Very Much. I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet

There are many possible way you can do this. Below is one of the possible way. And you can easily do this using jquery also.

```js
var txtColorClass = document.getElementsByClassName("txtColorClass");

for(var i = 0; i < txtColorClass.length; i++)
{
   txtColorClass.item(i).addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
  //event.target.style.background = "pink";    
  var txtColor = event.target.value; 
  event.target.nextElementSibling.value = txtColor;
  
}, true);

}


var colColorClass = document.getElementsByClassName("colColor");


function myFunction1() {
    //alert("Input field lost focus.");
    var txtColor = document.getElementById("txtColor").value;
 
    document.getElementById("txtColor").nextElementSibling.value = txtColor;
   
//    document.getElementById("colColor").value = txtColor;
}

function myFunction2(colColorBox) {
    //alert("Input field lost focus.");
    var colColor = colColorBox.value;
    colColorBox.previousElementSibling.value = colColor;
    
    //document.getElementById("txtColor").value = colColor;
}
```

```html
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtColor0" class="txtColorClass">
            <input type="color" id="colColor0" class="colColor" onchange="myFunction2(this)">            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtColor1" class="txtColorClass">
            <input type="color" id="colColor1" class="colColor" onchange="myFunction2(this)">            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtColor2" class="txtColorClass">
            <input type="color" id="colColor2" class="colColor" onchange="myFunction2(this)">            
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: I should have waited for a minute and copied your script. Thank You Nirali.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Very Much NewToJS with your hint i was able to resolve this.

```html
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtColor0" class="txtColorClass">
            <input type="color" id="colColor0" class="colColorClass">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtColor1" class="txtColorClass">
            <input type="color" id="colColor1" class="colColorClass">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtColor2" class="txtColorClass">
            <input type="color" id="colColor2" class="colColorClass">
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

<script>

var txtColorClass = document.getElementsByClassName("txtColorClass");
var colColorClass = document.getElementsByClassName("colColorClass");

for(let i = 0; i < txtColorClass.length; i++) {
    txtColorClass[i].addEventListener("blur", function() {
        var txtColor = event.target.value; 
        event.target.nextElementSibling.value = txtColor;
  })
}

for(let i = 0; i < colColorClass.length; i++) {
    colColorClass[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
        var colColor = event.target.value; 
        event.target.previousElementSibling.value = colColor;
  })
}

</script>

</body>
```